# How to remove specific element from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have tested different elements in a char array and if they do not meet the conditions I want to remove them from the array. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code sofar

```
String s;
    char[] b = inputString.toCharArray();
    b = new char[b.length];
    do
    {

        if(!(b[i]>='0')&&(b[i]<='9')&&(b[i]!='.'))
        {
            s = Character.toString(b[i]);
            if(s.equals("+"))
            {
                t = 1;
            }
            else if(s.equals("-"))
            {
                t = 2;
            }
            else if // and so on

            }
            else
            {
                t = 1029;
            }
            //want to delete element here if they fail if test
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us some code?

Comment: just tested the elements with a do...while loop and an if statement. My int i is incremented every loop and tests the elements with b[i].

Comment: Can't you use a `Collection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
ArrayList<char> charList = new ArrayList<char>(0);

for (int i= 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (b[i] == condition) {
        charList.Add(b[i]);
    }
}

charList.toArray();
```

Comment: i want to remove a char from chararray

Answer (score 2):

Because comments don't allow good code formatting:

At the beginning of your code, you get the `String` contents as a `char[]` and immediately lose it again by assigning a new `char[]` of the same size to the variable.

```
char[] b = inputString.toCharArray();
b = new char[b.length];
```

so the loop after works on a default-initialized array, not on the string contents. You need two array references to do the copying.

Answer (score 1):

It'd probably be a better idea to use a [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement here.  Rather than eliminating the character that you don't want from your array (mutation during iteration is evil unless you're using an `Iterator`), why don't you use the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class to catch all the characters you *do* want?

Answer (score 1):

You wont really be able to delete the element but you could change it by doing something like b[i] = 0; at the end of the given code.  Arrays are a certain length and the length cant be changed so if you want to remove that part of the array i would suggest using a list instead.

```
List temp = b.asList();
Iterator it = temp.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    if(it.next() == "t")  //your modification code here
        it.remove();
}
char[] newB = temp.toArray();
```

Something like this would work for you i think.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] finishedArray = new char[0];
char[] arrayToCheck = new char[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };
for( int i = 0; i < arrayToCheck.length; i++ )
{
    if( !doesNOTMeetSomeCondition( arrayToCheck[ i ] ) )
    {
        //DOES meet keep condition, add to new array
        char[] newCharArray = new char[ finishedArray.length + 1 ];
        for( int j = 0; j < finishedArray.length; j++ )
        {
            newCharArray[ j ] = finishedArray[ j ];
        }
        newCharArray[ finishedArray.length ] = arrayToCheck[ i ];
        finishedArray = newCharArray;
    }
}
//finishedArray contains desired result
```

A **list** would be much more fitting tool if you can change the data structure and are comfortable using Strings to contain the chars.

```
List<String> finishedList = Arrays.asList( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' );
for( String charInList : finishedList )
{
    if( doesNOTMeetSomeCondition( charInList.toCharArray()[ 0 ] ) )
    {
        finishedList.remove( charInList );
    }
}
//finishedList contains the desired result
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is not right with your program:

```
String s;
char[] b = inputString.toCharArray();
b = new char[b.length];
do {
    if(!(b[i]>='0')&&(b[i]<='9')&&(b[i]!='.')) {
        ...
    }
} while...
```

You're creating a `char[]` from your `inputString`, and then on the next line you assign a whole new empty `char[]` in your `b` variable. `b[i]` will in fact never be equals to `0`, `9` or `i`. Did you put that line here by error?

Then for the removing thing, I'd suggest too the use of an ArrayList where you will be able to iterate over it and remove the specific index you want to [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29) very easily.